# Adding decimal point, additional row w/ headers and rearranging columns in pythron script

Tags: python

I have the following code below which takes a specific type of .xml file and converts to a more reader friendly .csv file.

You can see what the reader friendly .csv looks like in the two linked .csv file output links below.

A few things I would like to add/change, but need help with altering my code to do so.

1.) I'd like to add one decimal position to column H so instead of reading say 20, I want it to read as 2.0. I'd also like to add one decimal position to any row that has CF in it, i.e. cell AE1, AG1, AI1, etc.

2.) I'd like to insert a row above row 1 where I can type in row headers. For example, H1 reads as T2. I want to insert a row above H1 that will say Accel./Decel. Time [s]. I'd like to be able to do this for every row in the spreadsheet.

3.) I'd like to rearrange the column order of the outputted .csv file. I'd like to move columns AD - BQ to where column I is.

Any help with any of these would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[.csv file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW5dT.png)
[.csv file output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyqAF.png)

```
from lxml import etree
import os
import pandas as pd
import collections


ProcessRecipe = collections.namedtuple('ProcessRecipe', ['recipe_number', 'recipe_steps'])


class File:
    def __init__(self, fp):
        fp_wo_quotes = fp.replace('"', '')
        if os.path.isfile(fp_wo_quotes):
            self.fp = fp_wo_quotes
        else:
            self.fp = None

    @property
    def parent_folder(self):
        return os.path.dirname(self.fp)

    def new_fp(self, file_name):
        return os.path.join(self.parent_folder, file_name)


class MPCProcessRecipe:
    RECIPE_TYPE = 'MPCProcessRecipe'

    def __init__(self, fp):
        """
        constructor
        :param fp: absolute file path to a recipe file
        """
        self.tree = etree.parse(fp)

    @staticmethod
    def get_columns(step_data):
        """
        Collect attributes from a step data element for CSV column header
        :param step_data: step data element
        :return: column names as a list of strings
        """
        _columns = ['Step']
        for data_element in step_data.xpath('./Data'):
            # <Data name="Repeat">0</Data> // without index
            # <Data name="MR" index="1"/>  // with index
            _name = data_element.get('name')
            _index = data_element.get('index')
            column_name = _name + _index if _index else _name
            _columns.append(column_name)
        # print('columns', _columns)
        return _columns

    @staticmethod
    def get_data(step_data_list):
        data = []
        for step_data in step_data_list:
            name = step_data.tag
            step = step_data.get('step')
            values = []
            for _data_element in step_data.xpath('./Data'):
                _text = _data_element.text
                if _text:
                    values.append(_text)
                else:
                    values.append('')
            datum = [name + step] + values
            # print('datum', datum)
            data.append(datum)
        return data

    @property
    def process_recipe_list(self):
        """
        Loop through <Recipe> elements and populate DataFrames
        :return: list of ProcessRecipe namedtuple
        """
        pr_list = []
        for recipe in self.tree.xpath('/Recipes/Recipe'):
            # <Recipe number="994" type="MPCProcessRecipe">
            data =[]
            if recipe.get('type') == self.RECIPE_TYPE:
                recipe_number = recipe.get('number')
                # <PreStepData step="1">
                # <StepData step="1">
                pre_step_data_list = recipe.xpath('./RecipeData/PreStepData')
                step_data_list = recipe.xpath('./RecipeData/StepData')
                # create columns from the first entry of StepData
                columns = MPCProcessRecipe.get_columns(step_data_list[0])
                if len(pre_step_data_list) > 0:
                    data += MPCProcessRecipe.get_data(pre_step_data_list)
                data += MPCProcessRecipe.get_data(step_data_list)
                df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
                pr = ProcessRecipe(recipe_number, df)
                pr_list.append(pr)
        return pr_list


def convert_xml_files_to_csv_files():
    fp_input = input('D&D a recipe file: ')
    file_obj = File(fp_input)
    print('File Path:', file_obj.fp)
    rcp = MPCProcessRecipe(file_obj.fp)
    pr_list = rcp.process_recipe_list
    for pr in pr_list:
        out_fp = file_obj.new_fp(pr.recipe_number + '.csv')
        pr.recipe_steps.to_csv(out_fp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert_xml_files_to_csv_files()
```

Comment: It is always best if you describe what you have tried and where you are stuck. Also try to ask a single concrete question at a time.

Comment: It is always best if you describe what you have tried and where you are stuck. Also try to ask a single concrete question at a time.